# How delete rows contains the following extensions with regex pattern?

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

> I want to make the line deletion based on the column "Script or expected file(s)", this column contains either the word 'technical' or empty or the extensions. The deletion is done only if the column is empty or if it contains the following extensions:
> .txt_go
> .zip
> .prd
> .xml
> .go
> .csv
> .txt
> or
> .xlsx
> or containing _00*

Comment: This appears to be just a list of strings, not a CSV

Comment: Also looks like you would like to remove all but the last line.. Wouldn't it be easier then to describe what you need to _keep_ ?

Comment: So you want to remove all records/rows from the CSV where the `Script or expected file(s)` column ends in any of those extensions, or contains "_00", and then write the remaining rows back to a new CSV? Is that correctly understood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Where-Object` to filter your data:

```
# import data 
$data = Import-Csv .\path\to\file.csv

# define list of extensions to filter out
$excludedExtensions = -split @'
.txt_go
.zip
.prd
.xml
.go
.csv
.txt
.xlsx
'@

# filter data 
$data |Where-Object {
  foreach($extension in $excludedExtensions){
    if($_.'Script or expected file(s)' -like "*$extension"){
      # immediately return $false and filter out row if ANY extension matches
      return $false
    }
  }

  # finally check for *_00* and return $true if not found
  return $_.'Script or expected file(s)' -notlike '*_00*'
} |Export-Csv .\path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you very much it work fine for me.

Comment: @Amakouladji Excellent, you're welcome! If this answer solves your problem, please consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left